# How to move divs to different position inside the same container div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have div called filterwrapper and it contain five divs.

I am using jquery .each to loop over and I want to actually move the divs to different position within the same div as specific locations. How can I best do that?

All the child divs have the same class and I don't want to change that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $filterWrap = $('#filter-wrapper .filter-container');

  $('#narrow-by-list').empty();

  $filterWrap.each(function (index) {
    var $currFilter = $(this);
    var $divParent = $currFilter.closest('.filter-container');
    var divHeader = $currFilter.find('.toggle-category-header').text().trim();

    if (divHeader === 'Color') {
      $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
    } else if (divHeader === 'Clothes Size') {
      $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
    } else if (divHeader === 'Price') {
      $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
    } else if (divHeader === 'Product Type') {
      $divParent.appendTo('$filterWrap :last-child');
    } else if (divHeader === 'Shop By Figure') {
      $divParent.appendTo('$filterWrap :last-child');
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Is there a specific bug/issue in your logic, or are you just seeking a code review?

Comment: Can you add some (minimal) html? That would help to understand the problem. The 5 divs you are talking about are the ones with class filter-container? Are they embedded in an element with the same class name (filter-container)? A .filter-container in .filter-container? Seems wrong, but that's what the jQuery code implies since you write `$currFilter.closest('.filter-container')`. But some html would help :)

Comment: I guess you want to grab the parent of each filter-container element? You could use `$(this).parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

just for information, the JavaScript language has had the [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement since its creation in 1995

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
  {
  const $filterWrap = $('#filter-wrapper .filter-container');

  $('#narrow-by-list').empty();

  $filterWrap.each(function (index)
    {
    let
      $currFilter = $(this)
    , $divParent  = $currFilter.closest('.filter-container')
    , divHeader   = $currFilter.find('.toggle-category-header').text().trim()
      ;
    switch (divHeader)
      {
      case 'Color':   
      case 'Clothes Size':         
      case 'Price':
        $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list')
        break;
      case 'Product Type': 
      case 'Shop By Figure':          
        $divParent.appendTo('$filterWrap :last-child')  // <--? bugg
        break;
      } 
    });
  });
```

(...and the Whitesmiths style since 1978)

Comment: Yes I am getting a bug there. Not sure how to put the last two in #narrow-by-list container. 

Color, Clothes and Price are ordered fine. 

The initial array $filterWrap order of categories are:

Color, Shop By Figure, Product Type, Clothes Size, Price

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda difficult to work out the problem since you didn't provide any html structure to work with. But here's an attempt:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $filterWrap = $('#filter-wrapper .filter-container');

  $('#narrow-by-list').empty();

  $filterWrap.each(function (index) {
    var $currFilter = $(this);
    var $divParent = $currFilter.parent();
    var divHeader = $currFilter.find('.toggle-category-header').text().trim();

    if (divHeader === 'Color') {
      $currFilter.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
    } else if (divHeader === 'Clothes Size') {
      $currFilter.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
    } else if (divHeader === 'Price') {
      $currFilter.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
    } else if (divHeader === 'Product Type') {
      $currFilter.appendTo('#other-list');
    } else if (divHeader === 'Shop By Figure') {
      $currFilter.appendTo('#other-list');
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter-wrapper">
  
  <div class="filter-container">
    <div class="toggle-category-header">Clothes Size</div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-container">
    <div class="toggle-category-header">Color</div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-container">
    <div class="toggle-category-header">Price</div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-container">
    <div class="toggle-category-header">Product Type</div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-container">
    <div class="toggle-category-header">Shop By Figure</div>
  </div>
  
  <h2>Other list</h2>
  <div id="other-list"></div>

  <h2>Narrow by</h2>
  <div id="narrow-by-list"></div>
</div>
```